# using AJAX to swap <div> contents based on screen size

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm getting to know vanilla JavaScript pretty well, but I don't know jQuery syntax, and I'm having a hard time with AJAX. I've read about 30 posts but can't make it work in my (relatively simple and common) scenario.

I have a WordPress site with dynamic header content (so I need to get WordPress/PHP variables on load), and I'm trying to load either a video background or the post thumbnail as a background image, depending on screen size (which I'm detecting with JavaScript). The detection script works (on load/resize), and I have PHP scripts that I can swap into my page that successfully get the video OR the image. But now, how can I swap them? (I don't want to load both, and show/hide, because that would slow down the page for image-only users.)

Here are some of the things I've tried, to no avail:

```js
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: '/wordpress/wp-content/themes/myTheme/home-video.php',
     success: function(data) {
       $('#theDiv').html(data);
     }
   });
```

```js
   $.get("/wordpress/wp-content/themes/myTheme/home-video.php");
   $('#theDiv').replaceWith('<?php include "/wordpress/wp-content/themes/myTheme/home-video.php"; ?>');
```

```js
   $('#theDiv').load('/wordpress/wp-content/themes/myTheme/home-video.php');
```

I'm sure I'm just confused about the timing of the PHP functions vs. the JS/AJAX functions, but I'm really at a dead end. If someone would help point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your first try is the way to go. What happens when you try it? Is the success callback called? Is it passed the expected data?

Comment: Thanks for adding these questions. Basic as they may be, it's helpful to a newbie like me to learn to trace the logic & troubleshoot in these situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajax gets handled in a different way in wordpress (see [CODEX](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins))

in your header.php declare your ajax variable.

```
<script>var ajaxURL = '<?php echo esc_js(admin_url('admin-ajax.php'));?>';</script>
```

in your functions.php

```
function Get_The_Header()
{
    if($_POST['whichOne'] == 'video'){
        get_template_part('home-video');
    } else {
        get_template_part('home-thumbnail');
    }
    exit();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_Get_The_Header', 'Get_The_Header');
add_action('wp_ajax_Get_The_Header', 'Get_The_Header');
```

and finally your JS

```
function get_header(){
    "use strict";
    var whichOne = "thumbnail";
    if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
        whichOne = "video";
    }
    var data = {
        action: 'Get_The_Header',
        whichOne: whichOne,
    };
    $.post(ajaxURL, data, function(result) {
        $("#theDiv").html(result);
    }); 
}
$(window).on("load", function() {
    get_header();
});
$(window).on("resize", function() {
   get_header();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured that I wasn't getting the PHP requests in during page load, so I wasn't able to retrieve the WP variables or add anything server-side to my page with JS afterwards. This is helpful.

The header.php script is straight-forward. The other two I'm trying to adapt to my either/or scenario, and I'm not quite there. I'll add my latest code below...

Comment: I modified my answer. I wrapped the event listener in a function and it runs on page load and page resize. this should work

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

OK, Mark. Here's what I've done with (to) the direction you've given me.

functions.php:

```html
function Get_The_Header()
{
 if($_POST['whichOne']=='video'){
  get_template_part('home-video.php');
 } else {
  get_template_part('home-thumbnail.php');
 }
 exit();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_Get_The_Header', 'Get_The_Header');
add_action('wp_ajax_Get_The_Header', 'Get_The_Header');
```

external JS file:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  "use strict";
  var whichOne = "thumbnail";
  $(window).on("load", function() {
    if (window.innerWidth >= 768) {
      var data = {
        action: 'Get_The_Header',
        whichOne: 'video',
      };
      $.post(ajaxURL, data, function(result) {
        $("#theDiv").html(result);
      });
    } else {
      whichOne = "thumbnail";
    } //end IF for screen detection
  }); //end listener function
}); //end jQuery function
```

Please let me know what I've done wrong, when you can. Thanks for your help!